# ICU equivalent of strerror(3) for getting the message for a UErrorCode?

Tags: icu

I've tried RTM, but: given an ICU `UErrorCode`, how can I obtain the corresponding error message string?  I.e., ICU's equivalent of `strerror(3)`.

Comment: (Note for others, ErrorCode::errorName() doesn't do it, that "just returns the error code enum as a string, not the error message".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const char *u_errorName(UErrorCode code) is the C version of ErrorCode::errorName - but there isn't an "error message" that is anything more than the enum name. That's a great idea, though- I'd recommend to file a bug. Or, consider contributing the code and data? Ideally it would be a localized message…